# how to implement custom http session in java?

Tags: java, httpsession

I will need to implement my own version of HttpSession in Java. I have found very little information which explains how achieve such a feat.

I guess my problem is - how do I override the existing HttpSession no matter the application server's implementation?

I did run across a quality but rather old read which helps me achieve my goal - http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Servlets/ServletControl/

Are there any other approaches?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. The JEE spec doesn't mandate that the HttpSession implementation is replaceable. But the main question is: why do you want to do this?

Comment: not sure if you need to know how to implement it, but check this http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html

Comment: What exactly do you need to do that you think you need to implement HttpSession?

Answer (score 8):

Its two ways.

**"Wrapping" the original `HttpSession` in your own `HttpServletRequestWrapper` implementation.**

I made this a short time ago for clustering distributed sessions with Hazelcast and Spring Session.

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-how) is explained pretty well.

First, implement your own `HttpServletRequestWrapper`

```
public class SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest original) {
                super(original);
        }

        public HttpSession getSession() {
                return getSession(true);
        }

        public HttpSession getSession(boolean createNew) {
                // create an HttpSession implementation from Spring Session
        }

        // ... other methods delegate to the original HttpServletRequest ...
}
```

After, from your own Filter, wraps the original `HttpSession`, and put it inside the `FilterChain` provided by your Servlet Container.

```
public class SessionRepositoryFilter implements Filter {

        public doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
                HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper customRequest =
                        new SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper(httpRequest);

                chain.doFilter(customRequest, response, chain);
        }

        // ...
}
```

Finally, set your Filter at the beginning in the web.xml to ensure it performs before any other.

The second manner to achieve it is **providing to your Servlet Container your custom SessionManager.**

For example, in [Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html).

Answer (score 5):

Create a new class, and implement HttpSession:

```
public class MyHttpSession implements javax.servlet.http.HttpSession {

    // and implement all the methods

}
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this myself:

Then write a filter with a url-pattern of /* and extend `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. Your wrapper should return your custom `HttpSession` class in `getSession(boolean)`.
In the filter, use your own `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

Comment: Yep - that I know but how do you get the application server (ie, Glassfish, WebLogic) to return the MyHttpSession when request.getSession() is called?

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: Today I currently use Glassfish 3

Comment: @plymouth5 In your custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper` you override both `getSession` methods to return your custom Session implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like it's easily doable in a portable fashion that would work among different containers, since the HttpSession implementation is provided by the J2EE container.

However, to achieve a similar result, you can implement a javax.servlet.Filter and javax.servlet.HttpSessionListener and in your filter, wrap the ServletRequest and ServletResponse, such as described in [Spring Boot with Hazelcast and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513673/spring-boot-with-hazelcast-and-tomcat).