# Getting hazelcast null pointer exception in jhipster

Tags: hazelcast, jhipster

I have generated my solution with hazelcast support in jhipster, but when I run as spring boot app only my dev environment. I am getting following execption on the console.

[WARN] com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter - session could not be load so you might be dealing with stale data
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.hazelcast.web.ClusteredSessionService.executeOnKey(ClusteredSessionService.java:183) ~[hazelcast-wm-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at com.hazelcast.web.ClusteredSessionService.getAttribute(ClusteredSessionService.java:225) ~[hazelcast-wm-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at com.hazelcast.web.HazelcastHttpSession.getAttribute(HazelcastHttpSession.java:114) ~[hazelcast-wm-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager.retrieveFlashMaps(SessionFlashMapManager.java:46) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractFlashMapManager.retrieveAndUpdate(AbstractFlashMapManager.java:92) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:885) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104) [metrics-servlet-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224) [websocket-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:353) [hazelcast-wm-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
[DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
[DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2]

Please help me to understand why I am getting this exception ?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting NPE because ClusteredSessionService is not initialised. Right now, WebFilter used with session replication does not support initialisation with `@ServletComponentScan`, instead you should register your filter with `SpringAwareWebFilter`. Here is a good answer for how to make that configuration : [Spring Boot with Hazelcast and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513673/spring-boot-with-hazelcast-and-tomcat)