# Invalidate session when user log in again

Tags: java, authentication, session, httpsession

I need to delete existing session if a user log again to my application, for example from another browser.

I'm using this approach:

```
public class LoginUserDetails implements HttpSessionBindingListener {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
   // All logins.
   private static Map<LoginUserDetails, HttpSession> logins = new  ConcurrentHashMap<LoginUserDetails, HttpSession>();

   private UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
   @Override
   public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) { 
   HttpSession session = logins.remove(this);
     if (session != null) {
      log.info("LoginUserDetails - Killing session {} ", session.getId());
      session.invalidate();
     }
    logins.put(this, event.getSession());      

    }
   @Override
   public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent arg0) {
     logins.remove(this);  
   }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return true; // fake
   }
 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
   return -1; //fake
 }

}
```

It works in my dev machine, but not in real environment where we have a cluster. The reason is simple: I have no previous session in map when the second attempt login is directed on a different node of the cluster.

A solution could be to save my sessionId on db eventually and retrieve the session ID at login ... but how can I invalidate a session from sessionId?

So, what could be a correct approach to invalidate the session correctly in any case?

Comment: Unless using sticky sessions (not recommended), there would need to be a shared resource among the cluster, such as a database like you mentioned or a cache.

Comment: Let's assume I decide to use a database, what should be the approach? I mean, should I save sessionId? And after, how can I invalidate session starting from sessionId?

Comment: The data is like any other data, just need to design the table(s), and have code to access the tables.   Whichever web container is being used should have hooks to plugin your implementation.  There are probably some out of the box implementations that will handle it.

Comment: I’m looking for a way to invalidate session by ID, to substitute session.invalidate() in my code. The rest (table structure or how to store and retrieve data) is not an issue. Please could you address a solution for this? I’m using websphere 7

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135096/how-to-implement-custom-http-session-in-java) might help.

Comment: I'm not able to understand how I could use HttpSession override to achieve my goal, sorry! Also, I was thinking to use a DynaCache resource in websphere to save the <user, HttpSession> information... but HttpSession is not serializable so I think it's not a good idea, am I right?

Comment: Hi Vjok, have you found a solution to invalidate a session by ID?  I am trying to do something like this on WAS.